# Amazon AWS Athena HIVE_CANNOT_OPEN_SPLIT: Error opening Hive split / Not valid Parquet file, parquet files compress to gzip with Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, gzip, parquet, amazon-athena

I'm trying to build skills on Amazon Athena.
I have already successed to query data in JSON and Apache Parquet format with Athena.
What I'm trying to do now is add compression (gzip) to it.

My JSON Data :

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "prenom": "Firstname",
    "nom": "Lastname",
    "age": 23
}
```

Then, I transform the JSON into Apache Parquet format with an npm module : https://www.npmjs.com/package/parquetjs

And finally, I compress the parquet file I get in GZIP format and put it in my s3 bucket : test-athena-personnes.

My Athena Table :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS personnes (
    id INT,
    nom STRING,
    prenom STRING,
    age INT
) 
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION 's3://test-athena-personnes/'
tblproperties ("parquet.compress"="GZIP");
```

Then, to test it, I launch a very simple request:  `Select * from personnes;`

I get the error message :

```
HIVE_CANNOT_OPEN_SPLIT: Error opening Hive split s3://test-athena-personnes/personne1.parquet.gz (offset=0, length=257): Not valid Parquet file: s3://test-athena-personnes/personne1.parquet.gz expected magic number: [80, 65, 82, 49] got: [-75, 1, 0, 0]
```

Is there anything I didn't understand or that I'm doing bad?  I can request apache parquet files without using gzip compression but not with it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: How are you compressing the parquet file? After generating the file or while generating the file using parquetjs?

Comment: Yes, I generate the file in parquet format and then compress it into gzip format.

Comment: It is not very intuitive, but the same error (`HIVE_CANNOT_OPEN_SPLIT: Error opening Hive split`) can be seen when there are insufficient Lake Formation permissions. The initial description is followed by `Forbidden (Service: S3; Status Code: 403;...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parquet file consists of two parts[[1]](https://www.ellicium.com/parquet-file-format-structure/):

1. Data
2. Metadata

When you try reading this file through Athena then it will attempt to read the metadata first and then the actual data. In your case you are compressing the parquet file using Gzip and when Athena tried to read this file it fails to understand as the metadata is abstracted by the compression.

So the ideal way of compressing parquet file is "while writing/creating the parquet file" itself. So you need to mention the compression code while generating the file using [parquetjs](https://github.com/ironSource/parquetjs/blob/master/parquet.thrift#L326)

Comment: Can you please mark this as answered if it helped you.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, 
I'm compressing parquet while creating it but still I'm getting this error.

Comment: @AbdulHaseeb have you verified the parquet file using https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/tree/master/parquet-tools ?

Comment: actually it worked. I was creating parquet file in buffer and then compressing it but later I compressed it at the time of creation and it worked. Thanks