# How to read parquet files from tar.bz2 using pyspark on EMR Notebook?

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-emr

I'm trying to read in parquet (snappy) files in a tar.bz2 format from an S3 bucket, but receive this error:
"java.io.IOException: Could not read footer for file"

when using:

```
df = spark.read.parquet("s3://bucket/folder/filename.tar.bz2")
```

I have downloaded one of the tar.bz2 files and verified that it is valid parquet within the underlying tar directory.

I also looked into using S3 Select in the boto3 package, but it looks like BZIP is only supported for CSV and JSON files currently, not parquet. I have also attempted to unzip the files back into S3 like this:

```
sc.install_pypi_package("boto3")
import boto3
from io import BytesIO
import tarfile

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket,Key='folder/filename.tar.bz2')
wholefile = obj['Body'].read()
fileobj = BytesIO(wholefile)
tar = tarfile.open(fileobj=fileobj)
s3.upload_fileobj(Fileobj=tar, Bucket=bucket, Key='folder/filename.parquet')
```

However, this simply yields a "Interpreter died:" error message without any additional information (possibly due to insufficient memory in cluster?). Is there a step that I'm missing to decompress the tar library?

Comment: How are these files compressed ? While they are getting created or after created?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy unfortunately I do not know, but I will try to get an answer. The data came from an outside group. Can you think of anything that would need to be approached differently in either case?

Comment: have you tried parauet tools to check this file schema?

Comment: I downloaded the file locally, unzipped and read the files into a DF successfully using spark.read.parquet, the schema is valid, it just doesn't seem to decompress correctly in EMR using my current approach.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59422714/4326922 also applies to any compression and any framework accessing parquet data